# "Крыльцо" во множественном числе

Tags: морфология

Задумалась: а как образовать множественное число от слова "крыльцо"? В родительном падеже: "крылец", а в именительном?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Ожегова, в Орфографическом словаре и словаре ударений- крЫльца: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%25EA%25F0%25FB%25EB%25FC%25F6%25EE&lop=x&gorb=x&efr=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&lv=x&pe=x&az=x

Comment: По-украински "крыльця" (вернее, правильно писать "крильця") — это "крылышки"))))

Answer (score 4):

Крыльцо - крЫльца, тут обсуждать особо нечего.
А вот насчет "маленького крыла"... Не совсем так, но в принципе - связь есть.

Давайте разберемся для начала что такое "крыло дома". Это может быть либо одна из двух половин длинной симметричной постройки (левое/правое крыло), либо - вне связи с этим представлением - некое "крылышко", элемент или пристройка, по форме напоминающее маленькое крыло. Первое в отношении крыльца исключается, второе - вполне. А почему бы и нет? Разумеется, это эпитет, этимология такая всерьёз не рассматривается.

Далее. Крыльцо - это действительно почти крыло, но с суффиксом -ЦО, который сейчас воспринимается как уменьшительный (пальтецо, винцо), но ранее имел более широкие функции. Отсюда же кольцо - от "коло", так что указанная IrinaGL аналогия в словоформах весьма точна.

Ну и самое главное. Крыльцо - от "крыть", грубо говоря - крытый вход в дом. Отсюда же и крыло, исходно - то, чем укрывают. Трудно сказать почему, но в основу легла именно эта функция крыльев, присущая больше нелетающим птицам, но это так.

Заметим разницу в значении суффиксов: кры**ло** - то, **чем** кроют (сравните: мыло, шило - то, чем моют, шьют); крыль**цо** - то, **что** кроют, что-то покрытое.
Окончательно: "крыльцо" - не прямой потомок "крыла", но как бы кузен. Ну или там племянник.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересный ответ. 

Про связь слов *кольцо* и *коло* тоже интересно. Действительно, ведь кольцо -- это маленький кружок. То, которое на пальце.

Comment: Про кольцо. 
Если точно, то это не кружок, а окружность. И не маленький. Тут суффикс не несет диминутивной функции. Кольцо - то, что-то *окруженное*. 
Я хотел даже написать, что это то, **чем** окружают (палец), но крепко усомнился в таком значении.

Answer (score 3):

Так же, как кольцо. 
А крыльцо это и есть крыло дома, малькое такое крыло.

Comment: Серьезно? Надо же! А мне и в голову не приходило. Спасибо!

Comment: >крыльцо это и есть крыло дома, малькое такое крыло

Как интересно!

Прошу помощь клуба знатоков! :-) Что, действительно слово *крыльцо* от слова *крыло* ?

Comment: Ответил в ответе. Простите за каламбур.